# How do I use a JS variable within JSON?

Tags: jquery, json

I'm attempting to create a postcode lookup JQuery script that'll be able to be used multiple times on a page, without having to duplicate the script for every address on the page. The Find button has the class "postcodeLookup" and the attribute "address" which is how I intended to get the script to populate the right address (it uses JQuery Populate plugin) & the inputs are named address[line1], where "address" is changeable (home[line1], office[line1], etc.).

The problem is how to get the JSON that populates the address to use the variable contents rather than the literal word "address"?

```
//postcode lookups
$(".postcodeLookup").click(function(){
    alert("I am The Postcode Finder...\nPretending to find the address...\nFound it!");
    var address = $(this).attr('address');
    $("form").populate({
        address: {
            line1: "First Line of Addr.",
            line2: "Line 2!",
            line3: "Line 3 of The Address",
            postcode: "PO1 1PO"
        }
    });
    $(".addressArea").slideDown('fast');
});
```

Comment: FYI, you're not using JSON there, you're using JavaScript's object literal notation. JSON is a *subset* of object literal notation that's simpler to parse. http://json.org

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var addrName = "office";
var address = {};

address[ addrName ] = {
   line1: "First line",
   line2: "Line 2..."
};

$("form").populate( address );
```

Now, when `addrName` is `office`, that will be the same as writing

```
address['office'] = { }
```

... which, in turn, is *exactly the same thing* as writing

```
address.office = { }
```

And that little piece of knowledge will be immensely useful in all aspects of javascript.

For instance

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    window['var' + i] = i;
}
```

Will actually create 10 variables in the window object (i.e. public variables) called `var0`, `var1`, ..., `var9`.

Ok, so that wasn't immensely useful, but you get the idea.

Comment: That trailing comma  (after the `line2` property) on your first example will make IE fail. IE doesn't like dangling commas, in either object literals or array literals.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: quite right! i was about to add more properties, but figured that those were really peripheral to the point, so i narrowed it down, but missed the comma. good catch.

Comment: No worries. (+1, btw) I was going to remove the comment since it's now outdated, but then I thought, maybe it'll be useful to someone finding this later, although they'll have to sort of imagine what I'm talking about. :-)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: they can always browse through the revisions of the answer =) yes, it's a valuable comment, indeed, although people will have to chance upon it. i've definitely struggled with this before, in arrays :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to do something like this, usually jQuery plugins work this way:

```
line1: function(data) {return youVariable},
```