# Javascript/HTML, is it possible to create variable names from a loop

Tags: javascript

Imagine i had: `<div id names>142,140,150</names>`

could i then (in Javascript) write a forloop which declares variable names, with these values appended ie

```
var list = document.getElementById('names').innerHTML.Split(',');

for(i=0; i<list.Length; i++){
    var 'beginning' + list[i];
}
```

so i'd essentially want to create:

```
var beginning142
var beginning140
var beginning150
```

Answer (score 7):

You can indeed:

```
window['beginning' + list[i]] = 'value';
```

Funny coincidence, I answered a very closely related question 10 seconds prior to this one, and then I used exactly this as an example. So [a more elaborate explanation on why this works is available here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156582/how-do-i-use-a-js-variable-within-json/3156618#3156618).

Comment: +1 for good answer. Javascript handles obj.test the same way as obj["test"], and since all variables that are global is stored in the window-object you can do window["test"] = "something"; alert(test); and get an alert-box stating "something".

Answer (score 5):

You can do something like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i<100; i++)
{
   eval("var beginning"+i);
}
```

For developers afraid from eval This is one of good articles talking about eval and how it is not an evil: http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2013/06/25/eval-isnt-evil-just-misunderstood/

> I’m not saying you should go run out and start using eval()
>   everywhere. In fact, there are very few good use cases for running
>   eval() at all. There are definitely concerns with code clarity,
>   debugability, and certainly performance that should not be overlooked.
>   But you shouldn’t be afraid to use it when you have a case where
>   eval() makes sense. Try not using it first, but don’t let anyone scare
>   you into thinking your code is more fragile or less secure when eval()
>   is used appropriately.

Comment: It works! In my opinion this solution deserves a good score, very clean and precise +1

Comment: "when you have a case where eval() makes sense" — Which isn't this one. JavaScript provides the Object data structure to handle this problem.

Answer (score 3):

I can't add comment to your question due to low reputation score - this is not answer but advice. 
I think It would be better to create single array with your keys 142,140,150...

Comment: His question was wheater or not this was possible, not if it's recomanded.

Comment: Nonetheless. A word of warning is required, as ‘variable variables’ are almost always a dreadful mistake. Most people asking here how to use them are Doing It Wrong in a major way.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you define an object that has those values as an attribute on it.

For example:

```
var myVariable = function(id, value){
 this.Id = id;
 this.Value = value;
};
```

then you can just instantiate this object. I think it is less complicated and more readable in the end.

Comment: +1 - with the flexibility of JavaScript objects aka `{}`, it's easy to forget that creating new types of objects is equally easy.